# UIImagePicker to display a saved image from a webView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my iPad app, the user selects an image from a `webView`. The saved image is presented in an `imagePicker` contained in a `UIPopOver`. The user can crop and resize the image, and when finished, the selected image is displayed in a `UIImageView`.

All of this works well, but to achieve it, the image selected from the `webView` is loaded into the user's library using the following code:

```
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
```

Ideally, I don't want the image to be saved to the library, because the image will not be required or saved when the app is finished. If it helps, here is the code I'm using to get the image from the `webView` into the library:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webPage.frame.size);
[webPage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil,nil,nil);
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: I have adjusted your code formatting, please format code properly when posting a question. Also tag the questions properly (which I have also done for you)  Further to that your question isn't clear. Its loaded into library, and you dont want it saved in the library? what library? camera roll?

Comment: @Jsumners Basically, how to get an image displayed in an image picker that is not selected from a users camera roll but from a UIWebView. As follows: UIImage -> UIImagePicker -> UIImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then save it into `NSDocumentsDirectory`:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docs = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *picture_information = [docs stringByAppendingFormat:@"/picture_name.png"];

//your code

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(webPage.frame.size);
[webPage.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

[UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage) writeToFile:picture_information atomically:YES];

//And you retrieve it like this:

 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:picture_information];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your help but how to I do get the saved img into the UIImagePickerController so the user can resize and crop.

Comment: why don't you make your custom viewController where you can do that?

Comment: I know it's a bit more work to do but if you want to use the DocumentsDirectory you should do that.

Comment: I could do that but Im not sure Im up to coding the whole resize and crop thing (which I need the user to do). This is shame because as the user plays my app it is unnecessarily filling up their camera library with unwanted images.

Comment: I don't see any other solution beside this.

Comment: USe this for cropping [Crop Image](http://iosdevelopertips.com/graphics/how-to-crop-an-image.html) and you can create a UIPinchGestureRecognizer for scale.

Comment: No problem, let me know if you encounter any problems and I'll help.